# How to build a sqlalchemy query that has a filter with the @> operator?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this flask/sqlalchemy query that works below:

```
paged_data = House.query\
    .with_entities(
        House.name,
        db.func.earth_distance(
            db.func.ll_to_earth(current_latitude, current_longitude),
            House.earth_location
        ).label('house_distance_from_current_location')
    )\
    .filter(db.text('earth_box(ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude), :radius)'
                    ' @> ll_to_earth(houses.latitude, houses.longitude)'
                   )
    )\
    .params(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude, radius=radius)\
    .all()
```

but I prefer to clean it up to look more like the code below...obviously it won't work quite like that...but I can't figure out how write it...in particular, the use of the `@>` operator which is not valid Python the way a `>` operator is.

```
paged_data = House.query\
    .with_entities(
        House.name,
        db.func.earth_distance(
            db.func.ll_to_earth(current_latitude, current_longitude),
            House.earth_location
        ).label('house_distance_from_current_location')
    )\
    .filter(
        db.func.earth_box(db.func.ll_to_earth(current_latitude, current_longitude), radius) @> House.earth_location
    )\
    .params(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude, radius=radius)\
    .all()
```

***Is there a way to do this, or do I just need to settle with using `text()`?***

For reference here is the `House` model (it uses a `create_materialized_view()` function which works fine):

```
class House(db.Model):
    __table__ = create_materialized_view(
        'houses',
        db.select([
            House.id.label('id'),
            House.name.label('name'),
            House.latitude.label('latitude'),
            House.longitude.label('longitude'),
            db.func.ll_to_earth(House.latitude, House.longitude).label('earth_location'),
        ]).where(
            db.and_(
                House.reviewed == True,
                House.deleted == False
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [op](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.op) method

```
.filter(
    db.func.earth_box(db.func.ll_to_earth(current_latitude, current_longitude), radius)
    .op('@>')(House.earth_location)
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks...I was missing `op`. I just didn't see it. You saved me a lot of time!